# Determine if a character is a forward slash

Tags: c

How do I determine if a character is a forward slash ('/ ')?

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
if (isupper(varToTest)) {//do something}
```

but for the life of me I can't find it.

Comment: your problem is you wrote forward slash as `'/ '` rather than `'/'`!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (varToTest == '/') { //do something}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 if (varToTest == '/') { /* do something */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple equality test will do .

```
 if (varToTest == '/')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if( varToTest == '/' ){ ...do something... }
```

Answer (score 1):

what about the simple way:

```
char a = some_func();
if (a == '/') {
    /* ... */
}
```